# Unbounded approximation of Sobolev spaces by smooth functions

Tags: sobolev-spaces, approximation

I'm trying to find a reference to show the approximation of $H^{k}(\Omega)$ by $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is equal to $R^{n}$ for $n \geq 1$.

The only things I found are the global approximation theorems by smooth functions, e.g. Evans 5.3.2 and 5.3.3. Is the statement not true or did I fail to find the right book?

Comment: This is not true.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Functions_vanishing_at_the_boundary

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how the section "Functions vanishing at the boundary" disproves the approximation on unbounded domains. Could you please go into more detail, maybe I'm just missing something small

Answer (score 1):

Compactly supported smooth functions ARE dense in $H^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (if I'm not mistaken..).  Because the integrability implies that they vanish at infinity.  On a bounded domain, $H^k$ doesn't necessarilly vanish at the boundary.  As seen here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Approximation_by_smooth_functions, you're good to go if you don't require compact support.

Comment: Thank you for help; I will try to find a cite for the density on an unbounded domain